# Are there any examples or tutorials showing Branch Version editing with ArcGIS Server JavaScript API?

Tags: editing, versioning, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, sample

I am trying to implement [branch versioning](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/geodatabases/overview/data-management-strategies.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_6FA2CFB5F9484FF096740D653C674B5D) in an application that I'm building using the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API.

I found a blog post showing [how to edit branch-versioned data in ArcGIS Pro](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-enterprise/data-management/branch-versioning-editing-administration/), and the [Version Management Service](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/version-management-service.htm) documentation shows the required syntax for each individual REST operation, but I was hoping to find a working demo or tutorial/blog post illustrating how to use branch versioning from start to finish.

For example, how to start the editing session and specify a new or existing version, then check in the edits and reconcile/post them, and deal with any conflicts.

Is there any example code or tutorial which illustrates how to use branch versioning while editing in a JavaScript application?

Comment: Does your JavaScript app have editing capabilities/widgets and does it include a Web Layer published from ArcGIS Pro? If so, I think the editing workflow should depend on your specific app.

Here's some documentation should help:

1. https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-enterprise/data-management/branch-versioning-setting-the-stage/
2. This video goes over some sample code on the REST API: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0TkcMs8U6Y 
3. This video has a demo in ArcGIS Pro: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyBjuoVhoD8

Comment: @JacobHelfman thanks. I'm no longer working on this project so I can't recall where I was stuck, but hopefully your comment will help others looking into this issue